# How to see command lines from app sent to Bluetooth

Tags: command-line, bluetooth, ipad

I'm trying to see the command lines that an iPad app is generating and then sending to a device via Bluetooth. Is there some kind of interface where I can "intercept" the commands?

Comment: Wireshark may help. On Ubuntu it is able to capture bluetooth traffic.

Comment: @N0rbert Do you know how? If so, make that an answer please!

Comment: O.k. I will give it a go... Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @FasterandhigherRast That was a comment.  Below is the answer: if that helped you, please do not forget to accept the answer by clicking the grey checkmark, turning it into a beautiful green! (thus advertising to other users that this answer helped you)

Answer (score 2):

1. Install wireshark

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wireshark
   ```
2. configure it to capture packets as normal user

   ```
   sudo chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
   sudo chmod o-rx /usr/bin/dumpcap
   sudo setcap 'CAP_NET_RAW+eip CAP_NET_ADMIN+eip' /usr/bin/dumpcap
   sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
   ```
3. launch it and start capture of bluetooth packets: on welcome screen in **Capture** part of window double click **bluetooth0**, perform some bluetooth-related actions on laptop or on iPad then analyze packets. You can stop the capture by **Capture->Stop** (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>).

Comment: This will only work if the PC is the device receiving the packets, though, as the bluetooth connection is encrypted.